# Speedy Q-Learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I've read on wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning

> Q-learning may suffer from slow rate of convergence, especially when the discount factor {\displaystyle \gamma } \gamma  is close to one.[16] Speedy Q-learning, a new variant of Q-learning algorithm, deals with this problem and achieves a slightly better rate of convergence than model-based methods such as value iteration

So I wanted to try speedy q-learning, and see how better it is.

The only source about it I could find on the internet is this:
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4251-speedy-q-learning.pdf

That's the algorithm they suggest.

[image]

Now, I didn't understand it. what excactly is TkQk, Am I supposed to have another list of q-values? Is there any clearer explanation than this?

```
 Q[previousState][action] = ((Q[previousState][action]+(learningRate * ( reward + discountFactor * maxNextExpectedReward - Q[previousState][action]) )));
```

this is my current QLearning algorithm, I want to replace it to speedy Q-learning.

Comment: *or another simpler source about speedy Q-learning.* - Requests for external resources are off topic, you should [edit] that part out.

Comment: ok... done. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first consideration: if you are trying to speed up Q-learning for a practical problem, I would choose other options before Speedy Q-learning, such as the well-known Q(lambda), i.e., Q-learning combined with elegibility traces. Why? Becuase there are tons of information and experimental (good) results with eligibility traces. In fact, as the Speedy Q-learning authors suggest, the working principle of both methods are similar:

> The idea of using previous estimates of the action-values has already
>   been used to improve the performance of Q-learning. A popular
>   algorithm of this kind is `Q(lambda)` [14, 20], which incorporates the
>   concept of eligibility traces in Q-learning, and has been empirically
>   shown to have a better performance than Q-learning, i.e., Q(0), for
>   suitable values of `lambda`.

You can find a nice introduction in the [Sutton and Barto RL book](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node72.html). If you are simply interested in study the differences between Speedy Q-learning and the standard version, go on.

A now your question. Yes, you have to maintain two separate lists of Q-values, one for the current time `k` and another for the previous `k-1`, namely, `Q_{k}` and `Q_{k-1}` respectively.

In the common case (including your case), `TQ_{k} = r(x,a) + discountFactor * max_{b in A} Q_{k}(y,b)`, where `y` is the next state and `b` the action that maximizes `Q_{k}`for the given state. Notice that you are using that operator in the standard Q-learning, which has the following update rule:

[image]

In the case of Speedy Q-learning (SQL), as peviously stated, you maintain two Q-functions and apply the operation `TQ` to both: `TQ_{k}` and `TQ_{k-1}`. Then the results of the previous operations are used in the SQL update rule:

[image]

Another point to highlight in the pseudo-code you post in your question, it that it corresponds with the synchronous version of SQL. This means that, in each time step `k`, you need to generate the next state `y` and update `Q_{k+1}(x,a)` for all the existing state-actions pairs `(x,a)`.

Comment: Thanks pablo! You are the best. Yes I'm trying to speed up Q-learning for a practical problem. I'm trying to make a bot for my game, with deep q-learning inspired by the Ataris bot. My neural network didnt do so well, So I took a step-back to check my q-learning and saw that the q-values didnt make much sense. I've found out that it was caused mostly because of some small bugs I had.
but on my way looking for a solution I came across speedy, and wanted to try it. I guess I'll try Q(lambda) instead

Comment: Thanks, it's a pleasure to be helpful :). Good luck with your bot project, it sounds very interesting.